# Convert while loop to functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, instrumentation

I am writing some kind of script editor to work with javascript, and I want the user to have the ability to execute the script. But I also want the user to be able to interrupt the execution of the code, for instance if they input `while(true) {}` by mistake.

I think there should be a way to automatically instrument the code by transforming this:

```
...
while(condition) {
    if (condition2) break;
    code;
}
following;
```

Into something like this:

```
var stop = false;

var g = function() { 
    if (stop) { throw; }
    following; 
};

var f = function() {
    if (stop) { throw };

    if(condition) {
        if (condition2) { setTimeout(g,0); }
        code;
        setTimeout(f,0);
    }
    else (setTimeout(g,0);
};

f();
```

2 questions:
- Is this feasible in all case?
- Is there a known component that would do it? It seems to me that it's hard to get everything right: variable scope, recursions, etc. But it also seems like this would be very useful to a lot of people...

Edited: added the stop flag, the flag could be set by the UI, during a setTimeout function

Comment: If your goal is only to prevent some code to run for too much time,  you should take a look at html5 workers, you are going to run the code you want on a separate thread, and you can terminate it whenever you want from the main thread.
It seems like a better option anyway if you want to run code written by your users

Comment: @Antoine: I can't really use webworkers because I am sharing a lot of data with the main thread.

Comment: Some async language extensions (`sleep();`) do this - they can transform synchronously written code into callback style.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't allow the user to terminate execution on demand, as the question proposed. It simply attempts to terminate execution if it goes on forever (more than the allowed time).

There are two different problems you need to address:

1. Determining if the execution is infinite
2. Exiting

---

The first problem is impossible to solve with complete accuracy, but a good heuristic is probably enough for you. You could set a limit to how long you let the program to run and if it goes beyond that limit you consider it will go on forever and thus force-stop it. You could do that by recording the start time and injecting a call to the following function after (or before) each instruction:

```
function __checkStop() {
  return Date.now() - __checkStop.__start >= 1000 * 60; // 1 minute
}
__checkStop.__start = Date.now();
```

The following code

```
var a = 3;
if (a < 2) a++;
```

Should be turned into this:

```
var a = 3; __checkStop();
if (a < 2) { a++; __checkStop(); }
```

If you don't want to build a full AST, you could inject the function call only at the more sensitive points, like at the begining of function definitions or loops.

---

The second problem is also difficult to solve. A simple solution would be to throw an error and catch it (or not) in the global scope.

It is not a perfect solution because a determined user (or an unlucky one) could simply catch your error and keep going with his infinite program. You could try to combine this with injecting some code into the try/catch blocks to re-throw your particular error if the user catches it by mistake in order to make it harder to beat. I for one don't know how this solution would fail. (If you know of a way to make it fail, please comment!)

Comment: while your solution is definitely possible, it represents the cheap way of doing this. I would be extremely interested in the full AST transformation solution, as this could lead to a lot more functionalities. And not have to rely on an arbitrary timeout.

Comment: The arbitrary timeout is [necessary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). As for parsing the source code and building an AST, yes you could do interesting things with it. The Google Closure Compiler is one example of that, providing static analysis, dead code removal, minification, etc.

Comment: no it's not, by using setTimeout, you give back the hand to the UI, and the user can press a key that sets a flag within the function, and based on the flag, you could stop the interruption.

Comment: Right, i wasn't thinking in the correct context. For some reason i was thinking about automatically stopping execution if it would go on forever. I will leave the answer, though something based on Bergi's comment might me more apropriate.